# Objective-C, Assign variable value to plist string

Tags: objective-c, macos, plist, nsmutabledictionary

I have a `.plist` file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>key1</key>
    <string>variable1</string>
    <key>key2</key>
    <array>
        <string>foobar</string>
        <string>variable2</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

My code looks like this:

```
NSString *variable1 = @"Hello";
NSString *variable2 = @"World!";

NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/path/to/file.plist"];

NSLog(@"key1: %@", [myDict valueForKey:@"key1"]);
NSLog(@"key2: %@", [[myDict valueForKey:@"key2"] objectAtIndex:1]);

// outputs
// key1: variable1
// key2: variable2
```

What I'm hoping to do is have the `variable1` and `variable2` in the `.plist` file use the `variable1` and `variable2` from the code (without specifically doing it in code), so the values from the `.plist` end up being `Hello` for `variable1` and `World!` for `variable2`.

Obviously assigning them like this is possible:

```
[myDict setObject:variable1 forKey:@"key1"];
```

**That's exactly what I'm trying to avoid**. Clearly the "variables" are merely strings in the `.plist` and obj-c doesn't think to assign them the values of the variables from the code. So the question is can I assign them the values from the code (like `<variable>variable1</variable>`), or somehow not make them strings? Or maybe this just isn't possible.

Note: I'm not a programmer, so please keep this in mind, thank you.

Comment: Probably write in info.plist is not good idea and it doesn't work because you are trying to write the dictionary to a .plist file inside your App bundle, which is read only. Thus it would not work and also would have more rejection chances even if you get it done other way.

BTW why Info.Plist only? I mean why you can not have it in other way like NSUserDefault and SQLite

Comment: @DhavalRaval: I don't actually want to write to the apps `.plist`, rather use the `.plist` as a template for the dictionaries that the app uses. The app is also an internal tool, not being offered in the AppStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is can I assign them the values from the code (like variable1), or somehow not make them strings?

Many ways, but...

> Note: I'm not a programmer, so please keep this in mind, thank you.

which presents obvious challenges! We've no idea how much you actually know, you've presented no attempt to do the actual substitution, etc. However you do make a good observation:

> Clearly the "variables" are merely strings in the .plist and obj-c doesn't think to assign them the values of the variables from the code.

Many beginners, and a few who aren't, confuse the difference between the character sequence `variable1` used as the *name* for a variable and the same sequence used as the *value* for a string – you correctly identify these are different things.

Let's see if we can help you along without a long lesson on program design. First we'll stick with your use of a plist for your dictionary (later given your suggestion of `<variable>variable1</variable>` you may wish to consider using your own XML).

Second we'll make the assumption that when a "variable" is used as a value in your dictionary it will always be the *whole* value and not part of it, e.g. you'll never have something like `<key>key1</key> <string>The value of the variable is: variable1</string>` and expect `variable1` to be replaced.

We start by modifying your code to read the plist from the app bundle and using modern Objective-C syntax to look up dictionary and array values:

```
NSURL *sampleURL = [NSBundle.mainBundle URLForResource:@"sampleDictionary" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:sampleURL];

NSLog(@"key1: %@", myDict[@"key1"]);    // dictionary lookup
NSLog(@"key2: %@", myDict[@"key2"][1]); // dictionary + array lookup
```

The file `sampleDicitonary.plist` has been added to the add and contains your plist. This outputs:

```
key1: variable1
key2: variable2
```

just as your code does.

Now instead of declaring your two variables, `variable1` and `variable2`, you can use a dictionary where the key is the variable name:

```
NSDictionary *variables = @{ @"variable1": @"Hello",
                             @"variable2": @"World!"
                           };
```

This represents the same information as your two distinct variables but crucially the variable names are just *strings*, and as you've already observed your plist contains strings – so now we have a problem of *string substitution* rather than *variable substitution*. To do the string substitution we utilise:

- A key lookup in a dictionary, e.g. the `myDict[@"key1"]` above, returns `nil` if the key does not exist in the dictionary;
- The expression `<expr1> ?: <expr2>` evaluates to the value of a `<expr1>` if the value is not `nil`, others it evaluates to `<expr2>` (This is a contraction of the *conditional expression*  – which you can look up.)

So if we assign the result of indexing into your plist to variable:

```
NSString *rawKeyValue = myDict[@"key1"];
```

and then look that value up in our `variables` dictionary:

```
NSString *substitutedValue = variables[rawKeyValue];
```

then if `rawKeyValue` has a value of one of the names your "variables" (`variable1`, `variable2`) then `substitutedValue` will be the corresponding value (`Hello`, `World!`). If `rawKeyValue` is not a variable name then `substitutedValue` will be `nil`...

But you don't want `nil` in the second case, you want the value of `rawKeyValue` and you can get that by utilising the `?:` operator which gives a replace of the first `NSLog()` of:

```
NSString *rawKeyValue = myDict[@"key1"];
NSString *substitutedValue = variables[rawKeyValue] ?? rawKeyValue;
NSLog(@"key1: %@", substitutedValue);
```

which will output:

```
key1: Hello
```

Doing these extra steps for every lookup is repetitive and tedious, and programming has a solution to that: define a method to encapsulate it and avoid using the intermediate variables. Here is a possible method:

```
- (NSString *)substitute:(NSDictionary *)variables in:(NSString *)value
{
   return variables[value] ?: value;
}
```

and with that defined the first `NSLog` becomes:

```
NSLog(@"key1: %@", [self substitute:variables in:myDict[@"key1"]]);
```

Hope that helps and gets you started. But do spend time learning programming properly if you're going to write programs!

Comment: This is great information, thank you very much for taking the time to explain it.